# Consider $f\big(xy + f(y)\big) = y\,f(x)$ then find the value of $f(y)$. Is there another way to approach the problem?

Tags: functions, proof-explanation

So the problem is as follows:

> Consider $$f\big(xy + f(y)\big) = y\,f(x).$$ Find the value of $f(y)$.

My friend showed me that $ \ (*) \ \ f(y) = 1 - y$.

*Proof*: By setting $x = 1$, we obtain $$f\big(y + f(y)\big) = y\,f(1).\tag1$$ Now, by setting $y=1$, we obtain $$\begin{align} f\big(x + f(1)\big) &= f(x) \\ \Leftrightarrow x &= x + f(1) \\ \Leftrightarrow f(1) &= 0.\end{align}$$ Consequently, equation $(1)$ becomes $$\begin{align} f\big(y + f(y)\big) &= 0 = f(1) \\ \Leftrightarrow 1 &= y + f(y) \\ \Leftrightarrow f(y) &= 1 - y \\ \\ \therefore \ f(xy + 1 - y) &= y\,f(x).\tag*{$\Box$}\end{align}$$ I found this solution to the problem very elegant, but I wondered to myself, *How do you know what method to use in problems like this*? In addition to that, is there another way of showing the truth of $(*)$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no guarantee that $f(x+f(1))=f(x)$ implies $x=x+f(1)$. Maybe $f(x)$ is just a periodic function with the period $f(1)$.

Comment: You never know what method to use. You try a bunch of stuff and see where that leads you. Inserting $0$ or $\pm1$ is a rather common place to start, though.

Comment: This is not conclusive, it uses twice the reasoning $f(u)=f(v)\Leftrightarrow u=v$. It's possible to show that from your equation, but it's not as simple as your friend seems to think.

Comment: There is one more possibility : $f(x) = 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, $f\equiv0$ is a trivial solution, too. Let's show that every non-trivial solution of $$f\big(xy + f(y)\big) = y\,f(x)\tag1$$ is one-to-one, i.e.
$$f(u)=f(v)\Leftrightarrow u=v\tag2$$ (and then, the reasoning above is correct, giving $f(y)=1-y$).
For that, we set $x=0$ in (1), giving $$f(f(y))=y\,f(0)\tag3.$$
If $f(0)\neq0$, we're done, because $f(u)=f(v)$ implies $f(f(u))=f(f(v))$, i.e.
$u\,f(0)=v\,f(0)$.
So we have to investigate the remaining case $f(0)=0$. Then, $f(f(y))=0$ for all $y$, implying $f(y)=0$ for $y\in f(\mathbb{R})$. If $f$ is not the trivial solution, there is a value $x_0$ with $f(x_0)\neq0$, and replacing $x$ by $x_0$ and $y$ by $y/f(x_0)$ in (1), we get
$$y=f\big(x_0y/f(x_0) + f(y/f(x_0))\big),$$ i.e. $f(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}$ and thus $f\equiv0$, a contradiction.